# 'Network permission' notifications for apps in Android 10 - turning off

Tags: notifications, permissions, mobile-data, android-10, toast-notifications

I have Android 10 on my phone. In the 'Settings - SIM card & mobile data - Mobile Data - Network Permissions' menu, I have set wifi & mobile data access as "disable network" for some of my apps.

The problem is, when I open such an app, it shows a notification "*App name* is Forbidden From Using the Network" with two buttons to choose from - "Keep disabled" or "Allow". This cannot be minimized or removed without choosing either of the two buttons.

After choosing "Keep disabled", the nuisance does not go away. Each time the app is opened next, there is a toast informing "Network is turned off for *App name*. You can modiy this in *menu location*". This happens every time! And sometimes (probably after a reboot, not sure) Android 10 forgets the setting for that app and the mandatory notification comes again with the buttons to choose from.

Can this behavior be prevented or at least minimized?

Answer (score 1):

Getting rid of that annoying notifications is possible but not easy. I had exactly the same problem and used Automate https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate to solve it.
In Automate I created a flow that waits for a notification to appear (you can define conditions which must be met to select only these unwanted notifications) and then executes 'snooze' operation on it. The length of the snooze time is freely adjustable, I chose 48 hours. That solved the problem once and for all.